# How can I put a Lion installer on a Flash Drive?

Tags: macos, install, adobe-flash

Could someone please list the steps to make a backup Lion install on a flash drive? Is it as simple as copying the Lion installer?

Comment: If, as you suggest below, your question is really "How to make a Lion installer if I don't have a Mac with (at least) Snow Leopard on it?" then that is a very different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to follow the instructions on this [page](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/08/make-a-bootable-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-installer-from-a-usb-flash-drive/).

Things you'll need:

- Flash drive bigger than 4 GB (8 GB+ would be best)
- InstallESD.dmg (extracted from the OS X Lion App, if you've saved it prior to the upgrade)

There's an alternate method mentioned [here](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/07/28/dear-aunt-tuaw-help-me-retrieve-the-lion-installer/).

**Note**: If you don't have the  Lion Install App, follow the instructions on this [page](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/02/re-download-mac-os-x-lion-from-app-store/) to download it again.

Comment: Thanks, great pointers. The problem with the first method - for me - is that I don't have the SL base system. I could rebuild one, but I'm lazy. The problem with the second solution is that it's obviously dicey. Maybe I will just buy the Apple dongle...

Comment: DON'T buy the Apple dongle… it's a terrible deal. It's expensive, it doesn't create a recovery partition, and it won't let you re-download from the Mac App Store if you need to later. Also, if you buy a new Mac in a year, it probably won't work with that either.